# Css и @media

Tags: css

Есть:

```
.wrapper{width:915px;margin:0 auto}
```

И есть:

```
@media screen and (max-width:945px) {
.wrapper{width:848px}
.content{width:503px}
}
```

Скажите, как сделать, если экран 945px, то `.wrapper` становится резиновым, а `.content` наследует размер.

Comment: max-width или width в %

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/f38z5ro0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@media screen and (width:945px){
.wrapper{width: 100%}
.content {width:inherit}
}
```